# how batch_sampler differs from sampler in pytorch dataloader module

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I am new to pytorch, and i am working on a project,I wanna know how `batch_sampler` differs from `sampler` in pytorch `dataloader` modules, i have been used sampler parameter before where i just passed data indices in sampler parameters using `SubsetRandomSampler`. I read documentation where `sampler` and `data_sampler` both takes iterables as parameters, so whats the main differences between them and when we need to pass `sampler` or `batch_sampler`.

Comment: `data_sampler` ? `dataloader` **module** ? Something is mixed up here. Do you mean what is the difference between `sampler` and `batch_sampler` in `torch.utils.data.DataLoader` **class** arguments?

Comment: Thanks @Proko for notice my mistake  and telling me about it._/\_